# Is it possible to save an entity that references an unsaved proxy?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

### Background

I have two entities in my project. One is called "Entity" and the other one is a relation. I use those to simulate a relation between objects in my game. So theres some sort of tree/hierarchy in my database... but thats not the case in my game. My entities are looking like this...

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class EntityPojo implements Serializable {

    @Id public long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<RelationshipPojo> relations = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "relationship")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class RelationshipPojo {

    @Id
    public long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
    public EntityPojo owner;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<EntityPojo> targets = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

### The Problem

It may happen that one of my ingame objects is being saved while it references an unsaved entity. Imagine this scenario... During my game i create multiple ingame-objects and their entity-pojos.
Then one of them ( the tile ) gets saved, but cant get a proxy of the unsaved object, that causes an ObjectNotFoundException.

```java
        var tile = new EntityPojo();
        tile.id = 1;

        var player = new EntityPojo();
        player.id = 2;

        var proxy = session.getReference(EntityPojo.class, 2L);     // Reference to unsaved player
        var inTileRelation = new RelationshipPojo();
        inTileRelation.name = "inTile";
        inTileRelation.owner = tile;
        inTileRelation.targets.add(proxy);                          // ObjectNotFoundException
        tile.relations.add(inTileRelation);

        // Tile gets saved before player was saved... 
        syncDatabase.save(tile);
```

### The Question

Why exactly does it happen and how can i prevent it ? Is it even possible to save a reference to another entity by having a proxy ? Just by having its id that the entity will have in the future ? How could i make that work ?

In SQL i would simply remove the constraints to insert the id itself... is this possible in hibernate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-get-reference):

> **Obtain an entity reference without initializing its data**
>
> Sometimes referred to as lazy loading, the ability to obtain a reference to an entity without having to load its data is hugely important. The most common case being the need to create an association between an entity *and another existing entity.*
>
> ```java
> Book book = new Book();
> book.setAuthor( entityManager.getReference( Person.class, personId ) );
> ```
>
> The above works on the assumption that the entity is defined to allow lazy loading, generally through use of runtime proxies. *In both cases an exception will be thrown later if the given entity does not refer to actual database state* when the application attempts to use the returned proxy in any way that requires access to its data.

So, you can use `entityManager.getReference` only if you know that your database has a record with specified id and you just want establish relationship without actual entity loading.

Comment: Thanks ^^ it works as expected when i save the entity before i reference it.